# Dependency injection container recommendation for MVC5?

Tags: c#, .net

I have experience with Symfony2 and now have the need to work with MVC5. Is there a Dependency injection container that works like the one provided in Symfony2. I am reading the documentation for Unity and examples on the web but It seems that it requires too much configuration.

Comment: Can you please go into more details what features you're looking for and how configuration should work? I know about a few .net containers but i don't know about how `Symonfony2` works. So your statement "works loke Symfony2" is totally meaningless to me. I also think that's appliccable to a lot of other users knowledgable in .net DI containers and why you did not receive any answer yet.